# MySQL trigger - problem with 'if' condition

Tags: mysql, sql

Each time I make an 'update' in my table I want to insert today's date in a 'date' column, but only if this cell contains '0000-00-00'

I'm trying this code:

```
IF (OLD.date = '0000-00-00') THEN SET NEW.date = now()
```

I get this error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax...`

What is wrong? I think I've already tried all :/

// EDIT

The whole query:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `my_name` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `my_database` 
FOR EACH ROW 
    IF (OLD.date = '0000-00-00') THEN SET NEW.date = now()
```

> Error: There is no OLD row in on INSERT trigger

If I'm adding just this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `my_name` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `my_database` 
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.date = now()
```

everything is fine...

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code segment published - assuming your actual code terminates the set and the if is closed with an end if; it should work fine. If it is and you still have problems please add your trigger code (including delimiters)

Comment: ... and the full error message indicating where the syntax error occured

Comment: Thanks guys! I've added more informations in the original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer lies in [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html):

> In an `INSERT` trigger, only `NEW.col_name` can be used; there is no old row.

Other issues with your code:

- you are missing the `BEGIN` and `END;` keywords around the code block
- the `IF` block must be terminated with `END IF;`

You trigger should be expressed as follows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON my_table
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF NEW.date = '0000-00-00' THEN
        SET NEW.date = NOW();
    END IF;
END;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/P8gVpVbUABpRzHrUqWFuQ/1)**:

```
-- create a test table
CREATE TABLE my_table(id int primary key, `date` DATE);

-- create the trigger
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON my_table
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF NEW.date = '0000-00-00' THEN
        SET NEW.date = NOW();
    END IF;
END;
//

-- insert a record with date value  '000-00-00'
INSERT INTO my_table (id, `date`) values (1, '0000-00-00');

-- check the content of the table
SELECT * FROM my_table;

| id  | date       |
| --- | ---------- |
| 1   | 2019-09-23 |
```

Comment: Thank for the answer, but still something wrong..
ERROR:
#1064 - Something is wrong in your syntax next to '' in line 6 ||

line 6 - SET NEW.date = NOW();

Comment: I can't add this trigger... I'm getting ERROR: #1064 - Something is wrong in your syntax next to '' in line 6

Comment: @proada: this seems to work fine. I added a DB Fiddle in my answer for your reference.